# Chafetz Chaim and Maariv

Tags: maariv

In the Sefer Shoshanos Yisrael which brings the psakim of Rav Shlomo Miller it mentions in a footnote that the Chafetz Chaim would sometimes daven maariv without a minyan while he was writing his sefarim. The source qouted is Kol Kisvei Chafetz Chaim introduction (Bereishis). However ,I am unable to locate the source ,anyone know where to find it?

Footnote-
[image]

Comment: It would seem that it is a compendium of his writings - https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/kol-kisvei-chafetz-chaim-hashalem-4-volume-set/36943

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a set called כל כתבי חפץ חיים with a few volumes. The last one is a compilation of many letters he wrote throughout his lifetime. The hakdama was written by his son and details many stories and actions about his father. The quote your looking for is on page 48 (see picture)[image]

Comment: +1 It should be noted this was written specifically regarding the time he was occupied writing the Mishna Berurah. Based on the surrounding ideas, the Chafetz Chaim was already an accepted halachik authority and he understood very well he was occupied with a work that would teach Halacha to the masses. This would not be a proof to anybody else to do the same, it would be along the lines of Rabeinu Hakadosh skipping prayers to teach the masses. The proof being that even in this quote, you see her would skip Mincha with a minyan too.